# How can I install a Printer that prints to a postscript file using vbscript?

Tags: windows

I have a requirement that through group policy all client computers needs to have a Printer installed called "PostScript Printer", every example I find online is for installing a network printer (which is not what I want).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A bit more info about that this printer is would be really useful

Comment: There is no printer. I'd just like to hijack some default drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code did the trick for me.  Not perfect, but it works.

```
Option Explicit

'On Error Resume Next
Dim oWshShell, objWMIService

Set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")  

Function PrinterExists(PrinterName)    
  Dim colPrinters, objPrinter

  Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
      ("Select * From Win32_Printer Where DeviceID = '" & PrinterName & "'")  

  PrinterExists = False
      For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
      PrinterExists = True
  Next
End Function

Sub RenamePrinter(NameBefore, NameAfter)
  Dim colPrinters, objPrinter
  Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
      ("Select * From Win32_Printer Where DeviceID = '" & NameBefore & "'")  

  For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
      objPrinter.RenamePrinter(NameAfter)
  Next
End Sub

Function InstallPrinter(PrinterName)
  If Not PrinterExists(PrinterName) Then
    Installing = oWshShell.Run("rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /if /f         %windir%\inf\ntprint.inf /r ""file:"" /m """ & PrinterName & """")
  End If


  Dim FailCount
  FailCount = 0

  Do While Not PrinterExists(PrinterName) And FailCount < 5
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    FailCount = FailCount + 1
  Loop

  InstallPrinter = PrinterExists(PrinterName)
End Function

Dim Installing

If Not PrinterExists("PostScript Printer") Then
  'XP makes this apple printer available
  If InstallPrinter("Apple Color LW 12/660 PS") Then
    RenamePrinter "Apple Color LW 12/660 PS", "PostScript Printer"
  Else
    'Don't know of a vista one yet
  End If
End If
```